# emu8086 struct not working

Tags: assembly, struct, structure, emu8086

I have basic knowledge of assembly and am using emu8086. I want to make a program which will save records. For example, in c++ we use structures to save multiple records.

The problem is I cant seem to find the right syntax which will compile correctly. I have searched a lot and syntax for different assemblies differ.
Below is the syntax I found for struct:

```
employee STRUCT

id db ?

name dw ?

employee ENDS
```

or this:

```
STRUCT MyStruct
 StudentId DW ?
 StudentName DB ? DUP(64)
END STRUCT
```

Comment: Different assemblers support different directives / syntax.  Check the emu8086 docs to see if it supports any kind of struct syntax.  You don't need any special syntax to store stuff adjacent in memory, because unlike C++, you control the layout of everything anyway and nothing can reorder your data or put padding between them unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: I don't believe EMU8086 supports the STRUCT directives that MASM supports.

Comment: Is there anyway someone today can get a copy of the old 16 bit tool sets? For example, Microsoft had an assembler, compiler, codeview (source level debugger), programmer's workbench (IDE), ... . You can run 16 bit code on 32 bit Windows, or you could install some version of DOS on a virtual PC. I seem to recall that there was an open source version of the Watcom tool set.

Comment: @rcgldr The legacy toolchains are still available on MSDN, if you have a subscription, such as through your school. And they are also available for download on various sites, if you don't have an ethical problem with that. (I don't; this is clearly abandonware, but the law may or may not agree with me.) Search Google for "Visual C++ 1.52", VC++ 1.52c was the last 16-bit version of the Visual C++ development environment, which bundled MASM, the C/C++ compiler, the linker, CodeView, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks for the info. I have the old tool sets, both Microsoft and Watcom C++ 10.0. My question was meant for others here. Microsoft compiler version is 8.00c, assembler (ML.EXE) is 6.11. There's also h2inc.exe which converts C .h files to assembly .inc files. VC++ 4.1 also includes VC++ 1.52 (maybe 1.52c?).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for answering.it seems emu8086 really dont support struct directives.